# PHP: development and production server question

Tags: php

Just a quick question. I have a developement server that I've changed various PHP settings in using different extensions, etc. I'm having a bit of trouble with the PHP installation on the production server. Can I just copy the PHP folder from development to production?

Thank,

Jonesy

Answer (score 2):

You need to document the extensions and parameter changes, then implement the same into the production server. This will also come in handy when you need to move to a new server.

Comment: so is that a no for copying the PHP folder?

Comment: Its less of a no and more of a "You should never put something on a production server that you can't reliable recreate and deploy yourself."  You should always be aware of what changes you're making to configuration files--not just on production, but on development.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean when you say PHP folder? Is that your application folder? Installed extensions are not stored in your application folder.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, if that's where PHP is looking for the php.ini file.
If you're running on Windows, it should be in the PHP folder, but it's also possible that the version being used is in the Windows folder.

Copying the PHP folder directly should work, but gAMBOOKa is right, configuring the new installation by hand will let you review each option, and help you familiarise yourself with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for available extensions, and even for PHP version, which may differ too